# ASP.NET Export - Response not ending?

Tags: asp.net, export

I'm trying to export some text to a text file, and that part works fine. The trouble is that the text files get a bunch of HTML/.NET output at the bottom of them... In other words, it's like the response isn't ending and the page is trying to write the rest of the page. Here's the code:

```
        Private Sub WriteData(ByRef Context As System.Web.HttpContext, Data As List(of String), fileName as String)

        With Context.Response
            .Clear()
            .ClearHeaders()
            .ClearContent()
            .AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName))
            .ContentType = contentType
        End With

        For Each curValue in Data
            Context.Response.Write(curValue)
            Context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
        Next
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
        Context.Response.End()
    End Sub
```

To call this, I just pass the HttpContext.Current and a list of data.

Does anybody know why this might happen? I'm not sure how to interpret it, and I've looked all over without much luck. My assumption was that the response wasn't actually ending with "Response.End()"...

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that you're using an `.aspx` to do this.

This would be a perfect scenario for a Generic Handler.  Try using `.ashx` instead.

Here is a pretty simple tutorial if you need more info:

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Generic_Handlers_%28ASHX_Files%29.html